# Reading ipython's magic "precision" value

Tags: ipython

You can set printing precision in `ipython` by using magic function `precision`:

```
In [1]: %precision 2                                                            
Out[1]: '%.2f'

In [2]: 5/7                                                                     
Out[2]: 0.71
```

You can also issue a command through ipython object:

```
ipython = get_ipython()
ipython.run_line_magic("precision", "2")
```

But how do you obtain the string `'%.2f'`?

Is there a command like `ipython.get_magic_value('precision')`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()
ipython.run_line_magic("precision", "3")
# you could also type %precision 3

form = ipython.display_formatter.formatters['text/plain']

form.float_format                                                                                           
#yields: '%.3f'

form.float_precision                                                                                        
#yields '3'
```